# Code for increasing clock speed of STM32F401 not working

Tags: arm, stm32, keil

I was trying to increase the clock speed of STM32F401 to 84Mhz using PLL. I tried for log time. But the code is not working. Can anyone check what needs to be done? External crystals is functional , because I checked that using HAL library.

The reason I am trying without HAL is that I've seen several document saying that the HAL consumes too much memory and it is better to avoid it.

```
void Enable_PLL_F401(void)
{
    //Enable The HSE
    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_HSEON;
    //Wait Until HSE Stabilizes
    //Remove While Loop; If the HSE isn't stabilized, code will stuck
    while(!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSERDY))
        ;
    /* Activate Prefetch Buffer*/
    /*        Optional         */
    
    
    //Configure the PLL registers
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC;  //PLL Source HSE
    RCC->PLLCFGR &=~ (RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM); //Clearing PLLM values
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_0 | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_3 | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_4);  //Divided by 25
    RCC->PLLCFGR &=~ RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN;   //Clearing PLLM values
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_4|RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_6|RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_8);      //Multiplied by 336
    RCC->PLLCFGR &=~ RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP;   //Clearing PLLP values
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP_0;  //Divided by 4
    RCC->PLLCFGR &=~ RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLQ;   //Clearing PLLP values
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLQ_2;  //Divided by 4 [USB-OTG Clock]
    
    RCC->CFGR &=~ RCC_CFGR_HPRE;         //System Clock Not Divided [AHB Prescalar]
    RCC->CFGR &=~ RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_DIV16;  //Clearing PPRE1 values
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_DIV2;
    RCC->CFGR &=~ RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_DIV16;  //Clearing PPRE2 Values
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_DIV1;    //AHB not divided [APB2 Prescalar]
    
    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;
    //Wait Until HSE Stabilizes
    //Remove While Loop; If the HSE isn't stabilized, code will stuck
    while(!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY))
        ;
    
    RCC->CFGR &=~ RCC_CFGR_SW;
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;
    
    while(!(RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL))
        ;
    
    //SystemInit();
    SystemCoreClockUpdate();
}
```

This is the clock configuration in CubeMX:

[image: Clock configuration in CubeMX]

Comment: Did you already look for HAL functions that may do this for you? Or use CubeMX to generate the correct code? That might save you a lot of effort.

Comment: I checked the HAL functions. It works fine. I'm going deep just for learning purpose.

Comment: If it's only for learning purposes, I'm not sure if it's so useful to ask for a solution here ;-) But to make this question more on-topic and answerable, I think you should at least add some details, like: What speed are you trying to configure it? How did you come up with this code (how did you determine the correct PLL values, register settings, etc.) Explaing that to us is a good learning method, and also helps us help you with it,

Comment: By the way "the code is not working" is never a good problem description. What is not working? Does the code hang, or run at a different frequency?

Comment: I've edited the description

Comment: "_The reason I am trying without HAL is that I've seen several document saying that the HAL consumes too much memory and it is better to avoid it._" Well, if you're writing code like this, I think the HAL might actually be more efficient. You write to `RCC->PLLCFGR` in 9 separate operations, which will result in a LOT of code. The HAL does this in 1 write, which is much more efficient, and probably better as well. There might be a number of invalid states in the meantime if you write to the register like this.

Comment: @wovano I've understood your point. As I have no point in this site I can't response your comment by upvoting. So I typed :)

Comment: I highly recommend using the HAL for stuff like this, because there are tens of things you can do wrong, and the HAL performs a lot of sanity checks. But if you really want to write it yourself, I recommend to thoroughly read the STM32F401 Reference Manual (RM0368), especially chapter 6, and especially 6.3, which contains the register descriptions. There are a lot of warnings. For example, you may not write to the PLLQ/PLLM registers if the PLL is enabled. Furthermore, it might be interesting to look at the generated assembly if you're interested in code size etc.

Comment: I didnt read the manual for you. do you need to adjust the flash wait states before bumping the clock up?

Comment: doing an and equal then an or equal is not remotely the same as a read-modify-write.  for the pll config register you might want to just do a single write without a read-modify-write, but if you want to do a read modify write, read the register into a variable, do all the read-modify-writes to the variable then write the variable to the register.   the way you have it here is going to get you into trouble some day i not already

Comment: did you show your pll math in the question?  how you confirmed you have the vco in the right range if there is a spec, and your multiplies and divides, etc?  and that you have not exceeded the bus speeds on any sub-system derived from the pll clock?

Comment: I verified the math though Cube Mx

Comment: This question is still not answerable. "_the code is not working_" is NOT a valid problem description. What is working, and what not? And most importantly, we already pointed out the obvious problems with your code (`PLLCFGR` should be written at once - the intermediate operation results should NOT be written to it, because it leads to invalid configurations). You did not seem to follow up on that. Furthermore, if you write "I checked that" or "I verified that", please explain HOW you checked/verified that, so we can check your reasoning. Thanks for adding the image though, that is useful.

Comment: I think the best way to "solve" this and learn from it is by comparing your own code with the CubeMX-generated code. You can repeatedly make small changes to the generated code and check if the code still works. That way, you'll quickly find out which changes are okay and which changes are causing the code to stop working.

Comment: This answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962656/stm32f407-register-level-clock-configuration-issue/62965869#62965869

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question is still missing some information, let me try to give you some pointers:

**Writing to MCU registers**

First of all, writing to the `PLLCFGR` register in many small steps is generally not the way to go. See the following piece of your code:

```c
//Configure the PLL registers
RCC->PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC;  //PLL Source HSE
RCC->PLLCFGR &=~ (RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM); //Clearing PLLM values
RCC->PLLCFGR |= (RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_0 | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_3 | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_4);  //Divided by 25
RCC->PLLCFGR &=~ RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN;   //Clearing PLLM values
RCC->PLLCFGR |= (RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_4|RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_6|RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_8);      //Multiplied by 336
RCC->PLLCFGR &=~ RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP;   //Clearing PLLP values
RCC->PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP_0;  //Divided by 4
RCC->PLLCFGR &=~ RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLQ;   //Clearing PLLP values
RCC->PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLQ_2;  //Divided by 4 [USB-OTG Clock]
```

This performs 9 writes to the same register. In the first write, you select the HSE oscillator clock. In the second write, you clear the division factor for the main PLL (`PLLM`). However, the value 0 is an invalid value. This might already cause issues (I don't think the behavior in this case is specified, so we can only guess what will happen).

This can be easily avoid by first calculating the correct value and then writing it to the register in a single operation like this:

```c
uint32_t reg = RCC->PLLCFGR;
//Configure the PLL registers
reg |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC;  //PLL Source HSE
reg &=~ (RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM); //Clearing PLLM values
reg |= (RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_0 | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_3 | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_4);  //Divided by 25
reg &=~ RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN;   //Clearing PLLM values
reg |= (RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_4|RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_6|RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_8);      //Multiplied by 336
reg &=~ RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP;   //Clearing PLLP values
reg |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP_0;  //Divided by 4
reg &=~ RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLQ;   //Clearing PLLP values
reg |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLQ_2;  //Divided by 4 [USB-OTG Clock]
RCC->PLLCFGR = reg;
```

The same applies as well to other registers in your code.

**Dynamically reconfiguring clocks**

It's not entirely clear to me if you want to increase the clock speed of the MCU *dynamically* (so when it's already running) or *statically* (so changing the initial configuration).

In case you want to change the clock speed dynamically, there a few additional things to consider:

- The Main PLL configuration cannot be changed once the PLL is enabled. So if you want to change the clock speed, you will first have to disable it.
- You have to make sure that there is at least one valid system clock at all times. If you're reconfiguring the Main PLL, you will have to temporarily switch to the internal clock (HSI).

Since I don't know your startup clock configuration, I can't go into more details, but I hope this will provide enough information.

**Flash wait states**

As mentioned by old_timer and Tagli, you might also need to adjust the flash wait states.
This is described in section 3.4.1 "*Relation between CPU clock frequency and Flash memory read time*" of the [STM32F401 Reference Manual (RM0368)](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00096844-stm32f401xb-c-and-stm32f401xd-e-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) (revision 5). The required value depends on your supply voltage and CPU clock frequency.

**Power Regulator Voltage**

To be able to achieve 84 MHz on the STM32F4, the regulator voltage scaling output must be set to Scale 2 (VOS = 2 in the PWR_CR register). This is the default after reset, but if your initial configuration was different, you may have to set it again.

---

NB: Regarding your statement "*The reason I am trying without HAL is that I've seen several document saying that the HAL consumes too much memory and it is better to avoid it.*"... There's a valid point in that statement, but it's not a general rule that you should follow. For low-level stuff like clock configuration, the HAL code is pretty basic and won't cost that much memory. And given the complexity of it, I wouldn't bother rewriting this, unless I *really* needed to save every byte of memory. The high-level HAL functions, e.g. for UART or I2C, are pretty big, since they try to cover many use cases, and you might save quite some memory by writing only the code you need. Still, I'd start with the HAL functions and only optimize when needed.